# ODP.NET are OracleParameter fields required for a stored procedure?

Tags: odp.net

Does anyone know the consequence of not setting all fields value on a OracleParameter in order to execute a storedprocedure?

For instance, is it necessary to provide OracleDbTypeEx, Size?

I would simply provide name, value, inOrOut?

What do you think?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For input parameters, type is infered from the value if it's not specified.  That said for code neatness and maintainability I tend to NOT set these properties for inputs, using the Parameters.Add method in a similar method to the AddWithValue method found on the SqlCommand class: cmd.Parameters.Add("myvarname", varvalue).

Length on the other hand does change the behavior.  IIRC, if you do not specify length, a form of overflow exception is raised when the value length exceeds the parameter length.  If you do set length, the input is trimmed to that length, at least in the case of String/Varchar.  I tend to stay away from setting length since I would perfer to be alerted of truncation and would instead limit input on the front end.

Output parameters are a different story.  Not setting output variable type and length tends to result in "character string buffer too small" and "illegal variable name/number," so in most cases you do need to set these properties for output parameters.